# Jquery background image effect transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I load images using background image tag for css in jQuery , i uso this function :

```
<script>
function url_image(id)
{
var valimg = jQuery("."+id+".cycle-slide").css("background-image");
jQuery("#sw_pic_ini").css("background-image",""+valimg);
}
</script>
```

When i use , all images onclick show over **#sw_pic_ini div** , the problem it´s only load , i try use add funtion **show** or other functions as **fadeIn** of jQuery but no show this effect over the image when load in background of this div

**I try also this with effect when background image it´s load , but no works :**

```
 <script>
    function url_image(id)
    {
    var valimg = jQuery("."+id+".cycle-slide").css("background-image");
    jQuery("#sw_pic_ini").css("background-image",""+valimg);
 jQuery("#sw_pic_ini").show(1000);

    }
    </script>
```

How i can create effect in background similar to transition when load ? , i try and finally no get

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: Use `var valimg = jQuery("."+id+"cycle-slide").css("background-image");`. Is your class `.{id}.cycle-slide` or `.{id}cycle_slide`

Comment: the class have 2 classes (".class1.cycle-slide")

Comment: and how you use this function??